# Assigning different schedules to one Cognos report

Tags: report, cognos-10

I have done a decent bit of research and have come up empty, I am looking for a way to assign multiple schedules to the same report in Cognos. I would like a given report to be emailed to different users at different times. I was looking into creating a Cognos job and trying to customize the subscription that way but haven't come up with anything yet. All of the methods I have tried strictly in Cognos Connection, from the UI. So, does anyone know if it is possible to have more than one schedule on a single report and going to different recipients each time?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The answer I posted before did not work, the report was changed to a pdf (from html) but an error was thrown presumably when the email action was to take place. It could be a viable solution for my goal but I will need to sort out the error.

Comment: The solution is, create a report view for each different schedule/person or group of people etc. Each report view can have a different schedule, different parameters and output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, created two separate report views in Cognos that run the same report.
Then edit each report view with the required schedule and different email recipients as needed.